# Namespaced constant results in error: NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following module/class structure:

```
module A
  module B
    class Foo; end
    class Bar
      MY_CONST = 42
    end
  end
end
```

I have put a binding.pry in my RSpec tests.  If I access

```
A::B::Bar::MY_CONST
```

I get the error: NameError: unitialized constant A::B::Bar

If I then do 
    A::B::Foo
I get the object A::B::Foo

Then, if I do
    A::B::Bar::MY_CONST
a 2nd time, I get 42.

If I embed Class Bar inside of Class Foo, and use
    A::B::Foo::Bar::MY_CONST
I get 42 directly.  However, I don't want to embed Bar in Foo.

What's going on here?

The RSpec code is inside a private function and looks like this:

```
    A::B::Bar::MY_CONST
```

Comment: Show me the RSpec please.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the requirement now is to embed Bar inside of Foo.  Doing that, I'm using:

```
A::B::Foo::Bar::MY_CONST
```

successfully.